# Add condition to PHP Function

Tags: php

The function below is from the SmartJobBoard script and its main job is to send an email notification whenever a job seeker applies to a job.

What I want is to put a condition that will make it run depending on whether an $application_email is present. If no $application_email is present, then the function should not run.

```
public static function sendApplyNow($info, $file = '', $data_resume = array(), $current_user_sid = false, $notRegisterUserData = false, $score = false)
{
    if ($current_user_sid) {
        $user_info = SJB_UserManager::getUserInfoBySID($current_user_sid);
        $sender_email_address = $user_info['email'];
    } else {
        $sender_email_address = $notRegisterUserData['email'];
    }

    $application_email = SJB_Applications::getApplicationEmailbyListingId($info['listing']['id']);
    $email_address = !empty($application_email) ? $application_email : $info['listing']['user']['email'];
    $questionnaire = !empty($info['submitted_data']['questionnaire'])?unserialize($info['submitted_data']['questionnaire']):'';
    $questionnaireInfo = array();
    if ($questionnaire) {
        $listingInfo = SJB_ListingManager::getListingInfoBySID($info['listing']['id']);
        $questSID = isset($listingInfo['screening_questionnaire'])?$listingInfo['screening_questionnaire']:0;
        $questionnaireInfo = SJB_ScreeningQuestionnaires::getInfoBySID($questSID);
        $passing_score = 0;
        switch ($questionnaireInfo['passing_score']) {
            case 'acceptable':
                $passing_score = 1;
                break;
            case 'good':
                $passing_score = 2;
                break;
            case 'very_good':
                $passing_score = 3;
                break;
            case 'excellent':
                $passing_score = 4;
                break;
        }
        if ($score >= $passing_score) {
            $questionnaireInfo['passing_score'] = 'Passed';
        }
        else {
            $questionnaireInfo['passing_score'] = 'Not passed';
        }
    }

    if (!empty($info['listing']['subuser']['sid'])) {
        $subUserInfo = SJB_UserManager::getUserInfoBySID($info['listing']['subuser']['sid']);
        if (!empty($subUserInfo)) {
            $email_address = $subUserInfo['email'];
        }
    }
    $data = array(
        'user'                  => SJB_Array::getPath($info, 'listing/user'),
        'listing'               => $info['listing'],
        'applicant_request'     => $info['submitted_data'],
        'data_resume'           => $data_resume,
        'questionnaire'         => $questionnaire,
        'score'                 => $score,
        'questionnaire_info'    => $questionnaireInfo);

    $email = SJB_EmailTemplateEditor::getEmail($email_address, self::SEND_APPLY_NOW_SID, $data);

    $email->setReplyTo($sender_email_address);
    if ($file != '') {
        $email->setFile($file);
    }
    return $email->send('Apply Now');
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$application_email = SJB_Applications::getApplicationEmailbyListingId($info['listing']['id']);
if(empty($application_email)) return; # New line
$email_address = !empty($application_email) ? $application_email : $info['listing']['user']['email'];
```